# Can you program Bluetooth 2.1 on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I've read/heard many things about CoreBluetooth and BTLE/4.0. Now my boss/project wants to be able to do what we have to do with 2.1 — is this even possible on iOS? I'm not doing anything related to Audio — I'm communicating with a device by sending/receiving Data/Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

iOS can only connect to Bluetooth 2.1 devices (apart from keyboards, headsets, speakers and so on) via the external accessory framework.  The use of this framework requires your device to be certified through the MFi program.

There is no support for a generic serial port profile without MFi

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case of HID (Keyboard) for example, how would that work? Sound devices I've seen some WWDC slides, but Keyboard I haven't. Any pointer to documentation?

Comment: You simply pair the keyboard through Settings->Bluetooth and then the onscreen keyboard no longer appears when a text element gets focus.  You can infer the presence of an external keyboard through the lack of a keyboard will appear notification when a text field gets focus

Comment: Being a developer, what I actually would like to do is simulate being a keyboard — I guess it takes me creating a virtual Bluetooth device and declare myself as a HID... Given: I'm still learning in that area. Thanks for all you pointers.

Comment: I have used a HID module in the past to connect a micro controller to an iPad by emulating a keyboard, but it was in a kiosk mode application - the problem is once you have an external keyboard paired the on-screen keyboard won't appear in any application - and of course you can't send data to a keyboard, only receive.  Now that BLE is available it is a much better approach